# How to set application properties in a ServiceBusMessage?

Tags: java, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

How can we add custom properties or application properties with the latest SDK azure-messaging-servicebus?

It seems something doable in the previous package com.microsoft.azure:azure-servicebu like the method setProperties(Map<String,Object> properties) but I cannot find anything with the new SDK...

It is also something doable with the .Net or Javascript SDK .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting application properties can be accomplished by using the `ApplicationProperties` map on `ServiceBusMessage`.   For example:

```java
ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage(ServiceBusMessage(BinaryData.fromString("Hello"));
        message.getApplicationProperties().put("EventType", "com.microsoft.samples.hello-event");
        message.getApplicationProperties().put("priority", 1);
        message.getApplicationProperties().put("score", 9.0);
```

More context can be found in the [ServiceBusMessage docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/java/api/com.azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmessage.getapplicationproperties?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebusmessage-getapplicationproperties()).